# Registros duplicados al aplicar operador '!=' y condición no aplicada en consulta

Tags: mysql

Estoy haciendo una mini tienda en línea y estoy presentando un problema a la hora de condicionar lo que se muestra según lo que hay en el carrito.

Es una tienda de segunda mano, por lo tanto las compras son únicas. Lo que quiero hacer es que lo que el usuario tenga en el carrito no aparezca más en el inicio de la tienda. Ya tengo el algoritmo hecho en PHP pero donde tengo problemas es en la consulta.

Esta es mi tabla de productos:
[image: Tabla de productos]

Esta es mi tabla del carro:
[image: Tabla de carro]

Y esta es la consulta que había construido para hacer todo eso:

```
SELECT productos.id,productos.nombre,productos.precio,productos.foto,productos.preciot,talla.talla 
FROM productos,talla,carro
WHERE productos.talla=talla.id AND productos.status=1 AND carro.id_u = $_SESSION[quien] AND productos.id != carro.id_p
```

Lo que quiero lograr es que seleccione toda la información del producto donde el estado del producto sea 1 (es decir, que está disponible) y que la ID del producto no esté agregada en el carro del usuario cuya ID sea la variable de sesión, es decir, el usuario que esté navegando en la página en ese momento. El problema aquí es que duplica los registros y además ignora la condición:

[image: Registros]

Estos son los datos que tengo guardados en el momento en mis tablas:
[image: Registros de la tabla productos]

Y estos son los datos que tengo guardados en la tabla del carro:
[image: Registros de la tabla carro]

Para hacer la prueba arriba, sustituí la variable de sesión por el ID 2 que es la ID del usuario con el que siempre hago las pruebas en la página, y como ven, tiene registros asignados en la tabla de carro.

Lo que se me hace extraño es que cuando aplico un operador diferente en la condición de que traiga todos aquellos productos que no estén en el carro asignado al usuario, por un igual, si funciona como debe ser:

```
SELECT productos.id,productos.nombre,productos.precio,productos.foto,productos.preciot,talla.talla 
FROM productos,talla,carro
WHERE productos.talla=talla.id AND productos.status=1 AND carro.id_u = $_SESSION[quien] AND productos.id = carro.id_p
```

*Resultado productos*
[image: Resultado productos]

Pero obviamente este no es el resultado que quiero, ya que quiero utilizar la tabla de arriba. El problema que identifico es el operador "diferente de" porque con el otro la consulta si funciona perfecta. ¿Quién me puede orientar?

Comment: Has probado de hacer un `INNER JOIN`, no estoy muy seguro, pero podria ser por eso.

Comment: A ver si esto te ayuda `SELECT
    p.id,
    p.nombre,
    p.precio,
    p.foto,
    p.preciot,
    t.talla
FROM
    productos p
    INNER JOIN talla t ON p.talla = t.id
    INNER JOIN carro c ON  p.id = c.id_p
    carro
WHERE
    p.status = 1
    AND c.id_u = $ _SESSION [quien]
  `

Comment: la solucion desde donde lo veo, un left join, ya que te trae todos los datos que no esten relacionado, ya probaste ?

Comment: @srjj Casi nunca utilizo el left join porque no lo comprendo bien.

Comment: brother lo que hacer ahi es un join implicito, que es casi lo mismo que inner join que trae las duplas relacionadas entre si, por el contrario, left te trae las que no esten relaconadas, dame un minuto te genero uno con tu ejemplo

Comment: @srJJGracias, aunque también me gustaría saber qué es lo que está mal en mi consulta, porque no logro identificar el error :/

Comment: lo que sucede con tu consulta es que en el moento del recorrido del query no puede compara excluir todas al mismo tiempo, por eso lo traer repetidos, @CésarEscudero

Answer (score 0):

¿Has intentado con un subquery?, algo así...

```
SELECT productos.id,
productos.nombre,
productos.precio,
productos.foto,
productos.preciot,
talla.talla 
FROM productos, talla
WHERE productos.talla = talla.id 
AND productos.status = 1 
AND productos.id NOT IN (SELECT id_p FROM carro WHERE carro.id_u = $_SESSION[quien])
```

Comment: Vale, esto funciona. Pero sabes por qué no me sirvió de la forma en que lo planteé yo?

Answer (score 0):

mira esta... tambien sirve al igual que el `NOT IN`

```
SELECT p.id, p.nombre, p.precio, p.foto, p.preciot, t.talla 
FROM productos AS p
INNER JOIN talla AS t ON p.talla = t.id
LEFT JOIN carro AS c ON  p.id = c.id_p
WHERE  p.status = 1 AND c.id_u = $_SESSION[quien]
GROUP BY c.id_u
```

espero te sirve, y la marque para los futuros, nos cuentas